# How do I draw radial circles in a spiral?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am very new with python.    You will be able to tell straight away by this question : I want to draw a series of circles (using turtle) sort of like spiral-graph. so far I can make different coloured circles but they all draw one on top of the other. I have a homework assignment to complete using turtle.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Welcome to stack overflow. For future reference know that this site is not a 'do my homework' site. Also something to keep in mind "[if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" Your question is also very vague "a series of circles (using turtle) sort of like spiral-graph" could mean allot of things

That being said I hope this helps and is the sort of series you are looking for:

```
import turtle


turtle.circle(50)
turtle.pu()          #pen up
turtle.sety(-50)

turtle.pd()          #pen down
turtle.circle(100)
turtle.pu()
turtle.sety(-100)

turtle.pd()
turtle.circle(150)
turtle.pu()
turtle.sety(-150)

turtle.pd()
turtle.circle(200)
```

in each block the turtle draws a circle then moves then picks the pen up and moves the turtle down so that the next circle's middle matches the original middle. The circles don't write over the last circle because they are not filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I don't know what boring, cut-rate Spirograph @Whud got to play with as a kid:

[image]

but I'm picturing the OP is looking for something more like:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from itertools import cycle

COLOR_NAMES = ['red', 'magenta', 'blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow']

colors = cycle(COLOR_NAMES)

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.speed("fastest")  # because I have no patience

for _ in range(36):
    yertle.color(next(colors))
    yertle.circle(50)
    yertle.left(10)

yertle.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]